# Weird alignment issues in table for list of courses

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table containing details of all my coursework. I wrote the following code. There are a few issues with it:

1. Why is it giving a blank 1st page upon compiling(with the table on the second page)?
2. The table seems to leave a lot of space on the left margin of the page, which could be used to have a wider 4th column, but I can't seem to be able to use that space.
3. The table goes over the page number on the bottom of the second page, and nothing gets displayed after whatever is displayed on Page 2. I have several other courses, and would like this table to span over approximately 3 pages. How can I do it?

Note: I have made the second column as a p-column as the real names of some instructors require two lines.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2cm}lp{6cm}} 
\toprule[2pt] 
Name of Course & Instructor & Book(s) Referred & Brief List of Topics Covered \\ 
\hline
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra I & ABC & Herstein; M. Artin & 
\parbox{6cm}{Basic Set Theory; Group Theory\\(upto Sylow theorems);\\ Introduction to Ring Theory} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra II & DEF & Hoffman and Kunze & 
\parbox{6cm}{Linear Algebra \\(upto Spectral theorems)} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra III & GHI & S. Lang & 
\parbox{6cm}{Ring and Module Theory\\(covering Hilbert basis theorem and structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups)}\\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra IV & JKL & S. Lang & 
\parbox{6cm}{Introduction to Field \\ and Galois Theory}\\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis I &  MNO  & T. Apostol & 
\parbox{6cm}{Real numbers; Sequences and series;\\ Calculus of a single variable \\ (upto Taylor's Theorem)
} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis II &  PQR  & T. Apostol & 
\parbox{6cm}{Riemann integral; Introduction to \\ Calculus of several variables; \\ Metric spaces and elementary \\ topological notions on it} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis III &  \parbox{2cm}{STU}  & S. Dineen & 
\parbox{6cm}{\textbf{Vector Calculus}: multiple integrals, \\ Jacobian formula, line and surface \\ integrals, Green's, Stokes' and Gauss' (Divergence) theorems; \\ Sequences of functions; Weierstrass \\ approximation theorem} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis IV &  VWX  & Rudin & 
\parbox{6cm}{\textbf{Introduction to Function Spaces}:\\ compact metric spaces,\\ C([a,b]) as a complete metric space, \\ Banach's contraction principle, \\ Stone-Weierstrass and Arzela-Ascoli theorems, Fourier series } \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory I &  YZ  & Chung; Feller & 
\parbox{6cm}{Combinatorial probability and urn models; Conditional probability; \\ Random variables; Expectation; \\ Moment generating functions;\\ Standard distributions(Binomial etc.); \\ Joint and conditional distributions; \\ Weak law of large numbers} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory II &  YZ  & Feller & 
\parbox{6cm}{Joint distributions; \\Transformation of variables\\(assuming Jacobian formula);\\ Distributions for sums, maxima/minima, order statistics, etc.; Standard multivariate and sampling distributions; Conditional expectation; Convergence of random variables} \\ 
\\[\defaultaddspace]

\bottomrule[2pt]

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: simple fix for (2): use `\noindent` before `tabular`.

Answer (score 6):

The real problem is that there is not enough room for the table in the page.

This is what I suggest:

1. Use `longtable` from the same package instead of `tabular` if you want the table to split over pages.
2. In this case the table can stay in one page. You can you use the `geometry` package and reduce the page margins only for the page where the table is with the command

   ```
   \newgeometry{margin=2cm}
   ```

   and restore the normal layout later by issuing

   ```
   \restoregeometry
   ```
3. Reduce the lenght of `\defaultaddspace` to `1pt`

   ```
   \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1pt}
   ```
4. No need to use `\parbox`es to center the contents of cells. You can load the `array` package and use `m` instead of `p`. You can also declare a new column type `M`

   ```
   \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
   ```

   You can also use `\newline` to issue line breaks inside cells.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} %only for the example

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\newgeometry{margin=2cm}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{2cm}lM{6cm}}
\toprule[2pt]
Name of Course & Instructor & Book(s) Referred & Brief List of Topics Covered \\
\hline
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra I & ABC & Herstein; M. Artin &
Basic Set Theory; Group Theory\newline(upto Sylow theorems);\newline Introduction to Ring Theory \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra II & DEF & Hoffman and Kunze &
Linear Algebra \newline(upto Spectral theorems) \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra III & GHI & S. Lang &
Ring and Module Theory\newline(covering Hilbert basis theorem and structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups) \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra IV & JKL & S. Lang &
Introduction to Field \newline and Galois Theory\\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis I &  MNO  & T. Apostol &
Real numbers; Sequences and series;\newline Calculus of a single variable \newline (upto Taylor's Theorem) \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis II &  PQR  & T. Apostol &
Riemann integral; Introduction to \newline Calculus of several variables; \newline Metric spaces and elementary \newline topological notions on it \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis III &  \parbox{2cm}{STU}  & S. Dineen &
\textbf{Vector Calculus}: multiple integrals, \newline Jacobian formula, line and surface \newline integrals, Green's, Stokes' and Gauss' (Divergence) theorems; \newline Sequences of functions; Weierstrass \newline approximation theorem \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis IV &  VWX  & Rudin &
\textbf{Introduction to Function Spaces}:\newline compact metric spaces,\newline C([a,b]) as a complete metric space, \newline Banach's contraction principle, \newline Stone-Weierstrass and Arzela-Ascoli theorems, Fourier series \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory I &  YZ  & Chung; Feller &
Combinatorial probability and urn models; Conditional probability; \newline Random variables; Expectation; \newline Moment generating functions;\newline Standard distributions(Binomial etc.); \newline Joint and conditional distributions; \newline Weak law of large numbers \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory II &  YZ  & Feller &
Joint distributions; \newline Transformation of variables\newline(assuming Jacobian formula);\newline Distributions for sums, maxima/minima, order statistics, etc.; Standard multivariate and sampling distributions; Conditional expectation; Convergence of random variables \\
\\[\defaultaddspace]

\bottomrule[2pt]

\end{longtable}

\newpage
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

As egreg notices in his comment, probably the table looks better if you use a normal `p` column without the need for additional `\\` before `\\[\defaultaddspace]`.

This is another possibility (choose the one you like most):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} %only for the example

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{2cm}lp{6cm}}
\toprule[2pt]
Name of Course & Instructor & Book(s) Referred & Brief List of Topics Covered \\[\defaultaddspace]
\hline
\\

Algebra I & ABC & Herstein; M. Artin &
Basic Set Theory; Group Theory\newline(upto Sylow theorems);\newline Introduction to Ring Theory \\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra II & DEF & Hoffman and Kunze &
Linear Algebra \newline(upto Spectral theorems) \\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra III & GHI & S. Lang &
Ring and Module Theory\newline(covering Hilbert basis theorem and structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups) \\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra IV & JKL & S. Lang &
Introduction to Field \newline and Galois Theory \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis I &  MNO  & T. Apostol &
Real numbers; Sequences and series;\newline Calculus of a single variable \newline (upto Taylor's Theorem) \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis II &  PQR  & T. Apostol &
Riemann integral; Introduction to \newline Calculus of several variables; \newline Metric spaces and elementary \newline topological notions on it \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis III &  \parbox{2cm}{STU}  & S. Dineen &
\textbf{Vector Calculus}: multiple integrals, \newline Jacobian formula, line and surface \newline integrals, Green's, Stokes' and Gauss' (Divergence) theorems; \newline Sequences of functions; Weierstrass \newline approximation theorem \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis IV &  VWX  & Rudin &
\textbf{Introduction to Function Spaces}:\newline compact metric spaces,\newline C([a,b]) as a complete metric space, \newline Banach's contraction principle, \newline Stone-Weierstrass and Arzela-Ascoli theorems, Fourier series \\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory I &  YZ  & Chung; Feller &
Combinatorial probability and urn models; Conditional probability; \newline Random variables; Expectation; \newline Moment generating functions;\newline Standard distributions(Binomial etc.); \newline Joint and conditional distributions; \newline Weak law of large numbers \\[\defaultaddspace]

Probability Theory II &  YZ  & Feller &
Joint distributions; \newline Transformation of variables\newline(assuming Jacobian formula);\newline Distributions for sums, maxima/minima, order statistics, etc.; Standard multivariate and sampling distributions; Conditional expectation; Convergence of random variables \\[\defaultaddspace]

\bottomrule[2pt]

\end{longtable}

\newpage
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to say `\let\newline\\` (it's already available). Using `p` for the last column avoids the need of "blank lines” between rows.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the comment. I didn't add your last suggestion in the answer because I don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: The OP wants a nice table. ;-) With `m` alignment it isn't. ;-)

Comment: You could avoid some of the severely-underfull-line look in the last group by replacing `maxima/minima` by `maxima\slash minima`. This will let TeX insert a line break after the slash (as well as inside "maxima" and "minima").

Comment: For some reason, both your codes are printing some strange things on the first page before printing the table on the second. Here is the first few lines of what they are printing on the first page upon compiling, any ideas? "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris."

Comment: Oops, just realized there was a "lipsum" used in the code and googled its use. Am a new LaTex user, so couldn't find out immediately and thought that my machine was giving strange outputs. Also, using "\newgeometry{margin=3cm}" outputs a "margin=3cm" text above the table. I believe that newgeometry hasn't been used in a proper syntax for this to happen?

Comment: @Ph3N0M Why do you think that `\newgeometry{margin=3cm}` is not the proper syntax?

Comment: Because upon compiling, "margin=3cm" gets printed on the top-left of the table. Also, I got the same result after deleting the newgeometry lines. I'm not familiar with newgeometry but I don't see how it changes any thing, as I am getting the proper table without it.

Comment: @Ph3N0M Strange behavior, it shouldn't happen. Try deleting the auxiliary files (at least `.aux`)

Comment: I'll try that now. But what changes will be observable if newgeometry works as expected?

Comment: @Ph3N0M The margins of the page are reduced to 3cm.

Comment: No luck even after deleting .aux file, still getting "margin=3cm" printed above the table. I have anyway made my table without invoking newgeometry and it looks fine.

Comment: @Ph3N0M Copy my example in a new file and try again.

Comment: @karlkoeller, still getting the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you do the following with the table, assuming it fits in one page:

- Use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, set its width to `\textwidth`, and use the `X` column type for the final column. This will set the width of the final column to (`\textwidth` minus the widths of the other three columns).
- Use raggedright typesetting instead of full justification in the final column; load the `ragged2e` package to allow hyphenation of words typeset in raggedright mode.
- Get rid of the various `\parbox` wrappers and use `\newline` statements to induce line breaks in column 4. (Thanks, @egreg!)
- Replace the many `\\ \\[\defaultaddspace]` instructions with `\\[\defaultaddspace]`. If you really need more vertical whitespace than what's provided by `\defaultaddspace`, simply increase the value of that parameter suitably. In the example below, I use `2.5\defaultaddspace` to provide more vertical space after the groups of algebra and analysis courses.

Assuming margins of `1in` all around, you'd get the following look:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l p{1.75cm} l Y @{}} 
\toprule[2pt] 
Name of Course & Instructor & Book(s) Referred & Brief List of Topics Covered \\ 
\midrule

Algebra I & ABC & Herstein; M. Artin & 
Basic Set Theory; Group Theory\newline
(upto Sylow theorems);\newline
Introduction to Ring Theory \\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra II & DEF & Hoffman and Kunze & 
Linear Algebra \newline
(upto Spectral theorems) \\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra III & GHI & S. Lang & 
Ring and Module Theory \newline
(covering Hilbert basis theorem and structure theorem for finitely generated 
abelian groups)\\[\defaultaddspace]

Algebra IV & JKL & S. Lang & 
Introduction to Field and Galois Theory \\[2.5\defaultaddspace]

Analysis I &  MNO  & T. Apostol & 
Real numbers; Sequences and series;\newline
Calculus of a single variable \newline
(upto Taylor's Theorem) \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis II &  PQR  & T. Apostol & 
Riemann integral; Introduction to Calculus of several variables; \newline 
Metric spaces and elementary topological notions on it \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis III &  STU  & S. Dineen & 
\textbf{Vector Calculus}: multiple integrals, Jacobian formula, line and 
surface integrals, Green's, Stokes' and Gauss' (Divergence) theorems; \newline
Sequences of functions; \newline
Weierstrass approximation theorem \\[\defaultaddspace]

Analysis IV &  VWX  & Rudin & 
\textbf{Introduction to Function Spaces}:\newline
compact metric spaces, $C([a,b])$ as a complete metric space, Banach's contraction principle, 
 Stone-Weierstrass and Arzela-Ascoli theorems, Fourier series \\[2.5\defaultaddspace]

Prob.\ Theory I &  YZ  & Chung; Feller & 
Combinatorial probability and urn models; Conditional probability; \newline
Random variables; Expectation; \newline
Moment generating functions;\newline
Standard distributions (Binomial etc.); \newline
Joint and conditional distributions; \newline
Weak law of large numbers \\[\defaultaddspace]

Prob.\ Theory II &  YZ  & Feller & 
Joint distributions; \newline
Transformation of variables (assuming Jacobian formula);\newline
Distributions for sums, maxima\slash minima, order statistics, etc.;\newline
Standard multivariate and sampling distributions;\newline 
Conditional expectation; \newline
Convergence of random variables \\

\bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

***Addendum***: It is straightforward to extend this setup so that the table can span multiple pages. One needs to (i) load the [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [ltxtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) packages (in addition to the `tabularx` package) in the preamble and (ii) make some changes to the header/footer structure of the table so that it conforms to the `longtable` syntax:

- Begin by placing the entire contents of the current table (from `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{...}` to `\end{tabularx}`) into a *separate file*. Call this file, say, `mybiglongtable.tex`. (I'm sure you can come up with a more suitable name...)
- In the "driver file", insert the instruction

  ```
  \LTXtable{\textwidth}{mybiglongtable.tex} % note explicit width indication
  ```

  right where you want the table to start. (A `longtable` isn't a "floating object" in the LaTeX sense of the word.) The driver file from the earlier, single-page table example would thus look like this:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,booktabs}
  \usepackage{tabularx,longtable,ltxtable,ragged2e}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
  \begin{document}
  \LTXtable{\textwidth}{mybiglongtable.tex}
  \end{document}
  ```
- In the file `mybiglongtable.tex`, make the following changes:

  - Change

    ```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l p{1.75cm} l Y @{}}
    ```

    to

    ```
    \begin{longtable}{@{} l p{1.75cm} l Y @{}} % no explicit width indication
    ```

    and change `\end{tabularx}` (at the end of the file) to `\end{longtable}`.
  - Using `longtable` syntax, provide the required header and footer information immediately after `\begin{longtable}{...}`, say as follows:

    ```
    \toprule[2pt] 
    Name of Course & Instructor & Book(s) Referred & Brief List of Topics Covered \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\emph{Continued from previous page}}\\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\emph{Continued on following page}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule[2pt]
    \endlastfoot
    ```

    Note that all rule-drawing commands for the tops and bottoms of the table are assigned to one of the commands `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot`.
  - The remainder of the file (up until `\end{longtable}`) should contain the "body" of the table, i.e., the information related to the courses. You can use `\\[\defaultaddspace]` and `\\[2.5\defaultaddspace]` as in the earlier MWE to provide some visual grouping of the contents.

Comment: The input with `&&&` is clumsy; why not simply using `\newline` when a line break is wanted?

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, I've incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: @Mico - From what I understand, I can't continue this table across multiple pages while still using tabularx, correct? In that case, I would not be able to use it as I need my table to span across 2-3 pages.

Comment: @Ph3N0M - I've provided an addendum to show how the suggested table setup could be extended to allow the contents to span multiple pages. The key is the use of the `ltxtable` package (along with the `tabularx` and `longtable` packages).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed addendum. However, I already used the longtable code with all four columns as p columns, as I had to finish the table soon.

Comment: What should I do if I want to add one extra column?

Comment: @Keith - Let me ask a couple of counter-questions: What kind of column? A fixed- or variable-width column? And, in which position should the extra column show up: First, last, or somewhere inbetween?

Comment: I just want to add one more column saying "Grade" in the current setting. I tried to do so by adding more $&$, but it did not work

Comment: @Keith - I assume the contents of the new final column should be centered. If so, you could (a) change `\begin{longtable}{@{} l p{1.75cm} l Y @{}}` to `\begin{longtable}{@{} l p{1.75cm} l Y c @{}}` and (b) before the terminator of each row, insert `&` and the (letter or numeric) grade.